# How to deploy a single multi tenant MVC application to multiple Azure virtual directories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, cloud

I have a single MVC.net web project that will be deployed for multiple customers

The code base and database structure is identical for each customer however on deployment, different CSS and images are used giving each customer their own look and feel.

Each application needs to have the same root url, mydomain.com. I would like to be able to configure so that when a user navigates to mydomain.com/site1 then they are shown customer A's specific deployment of the application. I would also like these deployments to be running on separate app pools (or similar).

- mydomain.com/site1
- mydomain.com/site2
- mydomain.com/site3

I'm currently deploying to an Azure cloud service and using SQL Azure for the database (one DB shared by each cloud service).

How can I setup the above structure using Azure cloud services and ensure that all our customers can use the same root URL but have different complete applications for all of the multiple sites?

Can this be done using virtual directories on an Azure cloud service?
If not, what would be the best way of achieving this?